# Computing a Poincaré Map and Section

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

I have a dynamical system where I know $x$ and $y$ as functions of time. How do I go about finding the Poincaré Map and Section in the phase space $y$ by $\dot{y}$? Like what are the steps I take?